# WordPress Access Attachment IDs in Thickbox Modal?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, thickbox

Im using a thickbox popup to edit some attachment custom fields.  The `attachment->ID` doesn't seem to be looping in my foreach loop after thickbox is called.  Only the first post ID is being grabbed by thickbox.  How can I get access to the attachment id in thickbox? In my code, the `<div id="my-content-id">` is being called up by thickbox.  Any attachment id in that div is not looping.  Attachment ids that are output on the page, not in thickbox are working fine.

http://pastebin.com/QhKyArkJ